# How to remove a line with a particular content in docx4j

Tags: docx4j

I want to delete a particular line in the docx if it has a particular word, say "killer".

How i can write a program using docx4j?
If i replace it with empty data, the line will be still there. I want to remove the whole line.
I tried something like this,

```
private void replacePlaceholders(WordprocessingMLPackage targetDocument,
            String nameOfTheInvitedGuest) throws JAXBException {

        List<Object> texts = targetDocument.getMainDocumentPart()
                .getJAXBNodesViaXPath(XPATH_TO_SELECT_TEXT_NODES, true);

        System.out.println(texts.size());
        Iterator<Object> itr = texts.iterator();

        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Object obj = itr.next();

            Text text = (Text) ((JAXBElement) obj).getValue();

            // System.out.println(text.getValue());

            if (text.getValue().contains("Hulk Hogan")) {
                itr.remove();
            }

            else {
                String textValue = replacePlaceholderOfInvitedGuestWithGivenName(
                        nameOfTheInvitedGuest, text.getValue());

                for (Object key : templateProperties.keySet()) {
                    textValue = textValue.replaceAll("\\$\\{" + key + "\\}",
                            (String) templateProperties.get(key));
                }

                text.setValue(textValue);
            }


        } 

        System.out.println(texts.size());
    }
```

But its still showing in the docx file.

Answer (score 1):

A `Text` element in a docx file has parent elements. The text will reside within a `Run` which in turn will sit within a block element like a paragraph (`P` node) or a table cell. If you're looking to remove a particular block element based on its textual content, once you've located the relevant text elements, you need to move up the parent elements, and remove them too -- for example, if the ultimate parent is a paragraph node, remove that.

If say, a paragraph displays as 3 lines in Word and you are trying to remove the 2nd line in that paragraph, then you have a different and more challenging problem.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help futur people :

```
if(((org.docx4j.wml.Text) o2).getValue().contains("WhatYouWant")) {
                                // if your text contains "WhatYouWant" then... 

                                Object o4 =((org.docx4j.wml.Text)o2).getParent();
                                //gets R
                                Object o5 = ((org.docx4j.wml.R) o4).getParent();
                                // gets P
                                Object o6 = ((org.docx4j.wml.P) o5).getParent();
                                // gets SdtElement
                                 ((List<List<Object>>) o6).remove(o5);
                                // now you remove your P (paragraph)

                                }
```

I had a content control (SdtElement) but I needed to put it in List < List < Object > > don't really know why but.... You might have something else so check in your document.xml before copy/pasting this.

This is for others who have a hard time, like I did to understand docx4j

Answer (score 0):

You could use Apache POI to remove Text from docx file as shown below.

```
    public static void removeTextFromDocx(FileInputStream inpudocxfile, String stringToBeReplaced,
        String stringToBeReplacedWith, FileOutputStream outputdocxfile) {
    XWPFDocument document = null;
    try {
        //loading docx file
        document = new XWPFDocument(inpudocxfile);
        for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : document.getParagraphs()) {
            List<XWPFRun> runs = paragraph.getRuns();
            for (XWPFRun run : runs) {
                //reading an entire paragraph. So size of list is 1 and index of first element is 0
                String text = run.getText(0);
                if (text != null) {
                    if (text.contains(stringToBeReplaced)) {
                        text = text.replace(stringToBeReplaced, stringToBeReplacedWith);
                        text = text.trim();
                        run.setText(text, 0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (XWPFTable table : document.getTables()) {
            for (XWPFTableRow row : table.getRows()) {
                for (XWPFTableCell cell : row.getTableCells()) {
                    for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : cell.getParagraphs()) {
                        for (XWPFRun run : paragraph.getRuns()) {
                            String text = run.getText(0);
                            if (text != null) {
                                if (text.contains(stringToBeReplaced)) {
                                    text = text.replace(stringToBeReplaced, stringToBeReplacedWith);
                                    text = text.trim();
                                    run.setText(text, 0);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        document.write(outputdocxfile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Could not create outputdocxFile --> IOEXception" + e);
    }
}
```